# Getting fields from another Jar File

Tags: java, reflection

I try to read fields from an external jar. We name the external File: 'Data.jar'.

Data.jar contains a class called `Constants` with some public, static, final fields. For example:

```
public static final String string1 = "Test"; 
public static final int integer1 = 1;
```

How can I access the external file in order to get the value of the fields string1 and integer1? Is it possible to use reflections? I know the external jar and the structure.

**Edit:**

The external jars structure is an older version of my current project. So I use the `URLClassLoader` and call the class `Constants`, I will get the value of my current project, and not the jars one. So is there a way to only call the external jars classes?

**Solution:**

```
    public Object getValueFromExternalJar(String className, String fieldName) throws MalformedURLException
    {
       Object val = null;
       // calling the external jar
       URLClassLoader cL = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { jarURL }, null);
//the null is very important, if the jar is structural identical to this project
       try
       {
          // define the class(within the package)
          Class<?> clazz = cL.loadClass(className);
          // defining the field by its name
          Field field = clazz.getField(fieldName);
          field.setAccessible(true);
          // get the Target datatype
          Class<?> targetType = field.getType();
          Object objectValue = targetType.newInstance();
          // read the value
          val = field.get(objectValue);
       }
       catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException
             | InstantiationException e)
       {
          LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "An error while accessing an external jar appears", e);
       }
       finally
       {
          try
          {
             cL.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
          }
       }
       return val;
    }
```

Comment: Load the JAR using `URLClassLoader`, load the class and access the fields using reflection.

Comment: Add the jar to your classpath first, only then you can access the contents present in the Jar. Right click on your project and go to  Build Path and then configure build path and there you can add the jar and rebuild the project and you can start using the classes from the Jar.

Comment: @raj240 Even if the added jar is identical to the projects structure?

Comment: Project structure doesnt matter, the resource which you want to consume needs to be on class path @Toni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example code using an `URLClassLoader` based on your description, as [dan1st suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66317589/getting-fields-from-another-jar-file/66317789#comment117243933_66317589):

```
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new File("Data.jar").toURI().toURL()});
Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("Constants");
String string1 = (String) clazz.getField("string1").get(null);
int integer1 = clazz.getField("integer1").getInt(null);
```

I guess you have to change the example to match your structure.

Comment: When I try this I get a `ClassNotFoundException`. I think that is because I don't write "package.Class". But when I do this, I get the values of my Project because I have the same fields in my running project. How to handle duplicate names? Can I somehow list all the classes from the loaded jar?

Comment: Ohh, so your project has the same class, but with different constants? Use `null` (or `ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader()` for Java 9+) as additional argument to the URLClassLoader constructor.

Comment: I can't believe it. It works!!! Thank you!!! @Johannes Kuhn

Comment: Okay sorry, and thank you. I added the solution to the Question.